# iteration within a while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, iteration

sorry to ask twice, but the other one was closed because it was missing important info and i apologize however my code is this:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "connect.php"; 
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
// Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the bio info 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bio\n"
. "LEFT JOIN bio_media \n"
. "ON bio.id=bio_media.bioid\n"
. "WHERE bio.id = ".$id."\n"
. "\n"
. " LIMIT 0, 30 ");
    // get all the bio details
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
         $name = $row["name"];
         $age = $row["age"];
         $division = $row["division"];
         $pic = $row["pic"];
         $story = $row["story"];
         $fb = $row["fb"];
         $tw = $row["tw"];
         $type = $row['type'];
         $file = $row['file'];
         $alt = $row['alt'];
         $title = $row['title'];
         $Age= DetermineAgeFromDOB ($age);
         while ($type == "image"){
                $images .='<a rel="lb[pp_gal]" href="images/'.$file.'" ><img width="60px" alt="'.$alt.'" title="'.$title.'" src="images/'.$file.'" /></a>';     
                break;
                }
        $i=-1;
        if($type == "video"){
            $i++;               
            $videos .='<li><a href="watch.php?id='.$id.'&v='.$file.'&ref='.$i.'?iframe=true&width=745&height=520" rel="lb" title="'.$alt.'">'.$title.'</a></li>';
            }
```

Question:  How do i get the "ref" portion of the url to update +1 for each entry in the database?

Comment: the ref portion of the url is not iteration  it just goes to 0

Comment: Use this, instead of `preg_replace()`: `if ( ! ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) die('Invalid input'); else $id = (int) $_GET['id'];`

Comment: ... you set $i to be -1, then increment it once - it will always be 0 in that case, yes.

Comment: webbiedave, it shows on mine but the code is: 
if($type == "video"){
            $i++;               
            $videos .='<li><a href="watch.php?id='.$id.'&v='.$file.'&ref='.$i.'?iframe=true&width=745&height=520" rel="lb" title="'.$alt.'">'.$title.'</a></li>';
            }

for all the entrys that come out, it shows the ref=0 it only adds to $i once

Comment: $i=-1; << might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have to get rid of `$i=-1;` in the loop and just put `$i=0;` before the loop.

By the way, you are overwriting your variables in the loop every time; either just add `$row` to an array and use that or don´t use these temporary variables at all and just use `$row` directly where you need it.

Comment: If i use $i=0 it then makes all of the ref=1.   i need it to count for each one.

could you be a little more specific with what you mean as far as $row?

Comment: @Symply No, you need to set $i to 0 before your while loop (the outer one).